# sonarqube sonar scan execution fail due to timeout

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to analyze a software with sonarqube but in some point after more than hour of execution we get a execution fail. I tried to increase the socket time out of the machine, timeout of the database ( postgresql) and also the time out of sonar properties to infinite but nothing fix the problem. In addition database, sonar and the source is in the same local machine. The error is the following:

```
INFO: 800/1880 files analyzed
INFO:       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:04:32.981s
INFO: Final Memory: 61M/1511M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file src/main/java/weka/core/pmml/jaxbbindings/TextModelNormalization.java
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:85)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:58)
at org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmPublisher.publish(ScmPublisher.java:85)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.afterSensors(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:60)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:90)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/core/pmml/jaxbbindings/TextModelNormalization.java'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:134)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineProperties(DAVUtil.java:253)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineInfo(DAVUtil.java:201)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getStableURL(DAVUtil.java:192)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getFileRevisionsImpl(DAVRepository.java:918)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getFileRevisions(SVNRepository.java:756)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNLogClient16.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient16.java:1390)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNLogClient16.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient16.java:291)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldAnnotate.run(SvnOldAnnotate.java:45)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldAnnotate.run(SvnOldAnnotate.java:17)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient.java:295)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:83)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.connect(SVNSocketFactory.java:164)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory._createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:124)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:94)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:236)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:415)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:888)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doPropfind(DAVConnection.java:146)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getProperties(DAVUtil.java:71)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getResourceProperties(DAVUtil.java:77)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:101)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:123)
... 45 more
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the  SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis timed out while the SVN client was trying to talk to your SVN server **emphasis** added):

> SVNException: **svn**: E175002: **timed out waiting for server**
>   svn: E175002: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/core/pmml/jaxbbindings/TextModelNormalization.java'

You need to diagnose why your SVN server is not responding to requests from your client:

- network issue?
- authentication?
- ...?

Answer (score 1):

In te project properties , I set sonar.scm.disabled=true .

Thanks!